# Maui with CRM / XRM nuget

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am trying to develop a Maui application using VS2022 to connect to an on premise CRM365 API and retrieve some data.

When adding Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly many errors appear. Is it not compatible with Maui? Is there anyway to speak to CRM365 on premise from Maui?

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Win32.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 DAA -> Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.1.1 -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.19.8 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives (>= 4.3.0) 
 DAA -> Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.1.1 -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.19.8 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives (>= 4.0.1)    Project1.csproj 1   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: System.Net.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 DAA -> Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.1.1 -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.19.8 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.unix.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.3.0) 
 DAA -> Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.1.1 -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.19.8 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.0.11)    Project1.csproj 1
```

Comment: Seems like you are using the .NETStandard framework and Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly only compatible with .NET Framework. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly` is a NuGet package built on .NET Framework 4.6.2. It is not compatible with MAUI, which is on .NET 6.0 or higher.

When connecting with Dynamics 365 CE from MAUI, try package `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client`. It is pretty new and designed for .NET Core and Dynamics 365 Online, but it seems to be the new way to connect to D365.

See also:

- [Dataverse Service Client is now Generally Available - MS PowerApps blog](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/dataverse-service-client-is-now-generally-available/)
- [Transition apps to Dataverse ServiceClient - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/sdk-client-transition)
- [Reference documentation - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client?view=dataverse-sdk-latest)
- [Sample code - GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/tree/master/dataverse/orgsvc/C%23-NETCore/ServiceClient)

Comment: Many thanks Hen I will try it out and check. Regards.

Comment: @AbedElHameedJaber, did you make any progress?

Comment: Actually I was very busy with other things that didn't allow me to try that out. Will check and advise. Many thanks

Comment: I have been following this issue for 2 days. It look like the new service client does not support connecting to crm on premise (CE). Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client.serviceclient.-ctor?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-powerplatform-dataverse-client-serviceclient-ctor(system-string-microsoft-extensions-logging-ilogger).